# I get error on my react-native app while I am trying to execute following code

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace 
  option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Setup the Environment before running the command

Follow these instructions

`brew install node`

`brew install watchman`

`brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`

**[Download and install Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)**

Choose a "Custom" setup when prompted to select an installation type. Make sure the boxes next to all of the following are checked:

1. Android SDK
2. Android SDK Platform
3. Performance (Intel ® HAXM)
4. Android Virtual Device

**Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc config file:**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

[You can also refer the official Docs here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)